# Editing Files from dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to add several lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf` in a Docker image.

Is there an idempotent way to do this via a `Dockerfile` rather than editing manually and using the `docker commit` approach?

Comment: Someone already requested this: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12193

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I would use the following approach in the `Dockerfile`

```
RUN   echo "Some line to add to a file" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

That should do the trick. If you wish to *replace* some characters or similar you can work this out with sed by using e.g. the following:

```
RUN   sed -i "s|some-original-string|the-new-string |g" /etc/sysctl.conf
```

However, if your problem lies in simply getting the settings to "bite" [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177059/refresh-net-core-somaxcomm-or-any-sysctl-property-for-docker-containers/26197875#26197875) might be of help.

Comment: Can you also add a environment variable to this file: - RUN echo $ENV_VAR1 >> /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: how to append content contains with newline.

Comment: what if I have to write more than one line, is writing echo that many number of times a good idea.?

Comment: this worked great for the one line I needed to add.  To add on a new line I just put in \r\n   ...  so the example above would be
RUN   echo "\r\nSome line to add to a file" >> /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: how can you use this in docker-compose.yml with `command: echo "line" >> /etc/file.conf` ?

Comment: What about multi-line?

Comment: @righto "Can you also add and environment variable?"  You can use -e to set the environment as part of your docker run command.  There's also a yaml syntax for a docker-compose.yml file to do the same thing at runtime.

Comment: For multiline, you can do the `RUN echo` for each line or do `RUN echo -e 'line1\nline2' >> /path/file`

Answer (score 18):

`sed` work pretty well to replace stuff, if you need to append, you can user double redirect

```
sed -i 's/origin text/new text/g' /etc/sysctl.conf
bash -c 'echo hello world' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

`-i` is a non-standard option of GNU sed for *inline* editing (alleviating the need for dealing with temporary files).

The `s` is the substitute command of sed for find and replace

The `g` means global replace i.e. find all occurrences of `origin text` and replace with `new text` using sed

Answer (score 3):

To complement the answers that already explain how you can append a single line, you can append multiple lines to a file like this:

```
RUN echo -e '\
Hello World!\n\
This is an example on how to\n\
append multiple lines to a file from within a Dockerfile.'\
>> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Use double quotes if you want to expand variables.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

```bash
COPY ./docker-build/www/_bashrc_append.sh /tmp
RUN cat /tmp/_bashrc_append.sh >> /root/.bashrc && rm /tmp/_bashrc_append.sh
```

That way I can edit `_bashrc_append.sh` with syntax highlighting in my IDE.