# Configure postgres in centos/postgresql-94-centos7 Dockerimage

Tags: docker, centos, postgresql-9.4

I would like to configure some postgres.conf parameters (`wal_level`, `archive_mode`, `archive_timeout`) in a Dockerfile that inherits `FROM centos/postgresql-94-centos7:9.4`

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing files from dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713362/editing-files-from-dockerfile)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a docker-compose file that mounts the pg data dir on host

```
    volumes:
      # See end of "Environment variables and volumes" section on
      # https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/postgresql-94-centos7
      - /path/on/host:/var/lib/pgsql/data
```

and have a script on host that edits the file and runs `docker-compose up` afterwards. 
(This depends on your setup, if you're not working on a PoC but on something more  permanent, it makes sense to edit the file when creating the docker image)