# Allow anonymous authentication on SonarQube 8.6

Tags: authentication, sonarqube

SonarQube 8.6+ [enforces user authentication by default](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.6/setup/upgrade-notes/).

How do I allow anonymous access since the first startup?

I am running SonarQube on a local Docker Container and I would like to automate this step. That is, I am looking for a solution not involving:

1. Log on to SonarQube with the [default credentials](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.6/instance-administration/security/) (login: `admin`, password: `admin`).
2. [Change the default password](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1352).
3. Manually disable the [**Force user authentication**](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.6/instance-administration/security/) property from **Administration > Configuration > General Settings > Security**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could enable the anonymous access by adding the following property to the `$SONARQUBE-HOME/conf/sonar.properties` file:

```
sonar.forceAuthentication=false
```

How to modify the file in Docker you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27714071/4944847