# Inconsistent runtime kernel parameters in DOCKER container and on host

Tags: hadoop, docker, ibm-cloud, sysctl, biginsights

my host is on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and I'm using the latest centos base image in order to create a DOCKER image of IBM InfoSphere BigInsights in order to push it to the Bluemix Container Cloud.

I've solved nearly everything but I'm stuck with setting runtime kernel parameters using sysctl because they have the wrong value and the installer complains.

```
sysctl -a |grep net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    61000
```

Of course it is not possible to set them inside the DOCKER container, I get the following error:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 64000"
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range": Read-only file system
```

So I've set the parameters on the host system:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 64000"
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 64000

sudo sysctl -a |grep net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 64000
```

I've even rebuilt the whole image and re-created the container but still inside the DOCKER container I get:

```
sysctl -a |grep net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    61000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Refresh net.core.somaxcomm (or any sysctl property) for docker containers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177059/refresh-net-core-somaxcomm-or-any-sysctl-property-for-docker-containers/26197875#26197875

Comment: very good point, unfortunately there is no /proc/net.ipv4 on my host system, but I got your point and will think about it

Comment: But then once I set the host's kernel parameter through DOCKER IMHO there is no difference in setting them on the hosts system itself :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload sysctl.  Give one of the following commands a try (they depend on your OS)

`sudo /etc/rc.d/sysctl reload`

or

`sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: Hi, I have set the parameters on the host system and build the image from scratch but still have the wrong parameters in the running docker container

Comment: I updated my answer above, that should reload sysctl.

Comment: Can you paste the error from running either/both of those commands?

Comment: Are you still having this issue?